# Copy non-blank rows to new tab fast

Tags: excel, vba

I am a novice, just starting to use VBA.  I have the following code that works for what I am doing, but as my range has become 800 rows long, it has become very slow to execute.  I'm hoping someone can suggest changes to make this run faster.

I have my Summary Sheet, which I pre-populate with values of column A and C from several other tabs, then I run the following macro to hide the blank rows, based on column B having any value besides blank.

I only want the tabs that have relevant systems to show on the summary tab, so I use the "E" qualifier based on a formula in that cell of the summary sheet, so it hides the non-needed systems.

So my loop happens twice, once for blank rows, and the second to hide non-needed systems.

Thank all for your code/comments.  However, I am rethinking this project, and would like your thoughts on if the following is a better approach.  First, what I'm trying to accomplish:
I am trying to generate a Proposal that shows only the systems that the user wants to include in their proposal. Each tab is a separate estimate for a system.  I have a Project Info tab listing each system that the user chooses Y or N to include only the systems he wants to estimate, allowing the user to choose if they want to include the system or not.  So, I have a button on the Summary tab that should only pull the systems marked "Y" from the Project Info tab, go to that tab, pull the rows that have a quantity >0, and list them on the Summary tab to show the Bill of Materials for each system.

So I am thinking a better way to accomplish this is, Check for a Y, or Y, then go to that system tab, sort the rows so only rows with column 2 >0 are the result of the filter, then copy these rows to the Summary tab, then go to next tab with a "Y".

Is this a better way to generate this summary tab?

```
Sub Summary_BOM()
'
' Hide Empty Rows Macro

Rows("72:808").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False

    BeginRow = 72
    EndRow = 808
    ChkCol = 2

    For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
        If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value < 1 Then
           Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next RowCnt

' RemoveUnusedSystems Macro
'
    Rows("72:808").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False

    BeginRow = 72
    EndRow = 808
    ChkCol = 5

    For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
        If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = "E" Then
            Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next RowCnt

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Range("A71").Select

    MsgBox ("   Systems and BOM Update Complete!   ")

End Sub
```

Comment: I concur with @findwindow - just filter your table, then copy the appropriate cells.

Comment: What are you evaluating in `If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value < 1 Then`? Doesn't seem related to evaluating if cell is empty? Unless it's some obscure way to determine if cell is blank? The first thing I would suggest is to only do 1 pass and evaluate both conditions on the same loop. No reason to loop back again when conditions are exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using the following script for your requested purpose:

```
Sub Summary_BOM()
'
' Hide Empty Rows Macro

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B72:B808")

    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        If cell.Value2 = "" Or cell.Offset(0, 3).Value2 = "E" Then
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next cell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox ("   Systems and BOM Update Complete!   ")

End Sub
```

The script will hopefully be more efficient because you are only doing 1 loop and evaluating both conditions at the same time. It also doesn't use `.Select` which tends to slow down scripts. You can add further conditions to the if either with `And` or `Or` as well as through an `ElseIf`. Regards,

EDIT: As per Marco Getrost's very valid indication I have changed the second condition of the `If` statement to evaluate 3 columns to the right of the looped cell.

Comment: You need to be careful, he checks for column "B" in the first loop and "E" in the second. You only check "B" for both.

Comment: @Marco Getrost Good point, had not noticed that he changed his "check column". I have edited my answer appropriately. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub test()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim BeginRow As Long, EndRow As Long, c As Long

BeginRow = 72
EndRow = 808

With ActiveSheet

For c = BeginRow To EndRow

If .Cells(c, 2).Value < 1 Or .Cells(c, 5).Value = "E" Then

    .Rows(c).EntireRow.Hidden = True

End If

Next

End With

MsgBox "complete"

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```